# How is this regex splitting this string?

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm having a problem unraveling some Java code sent me. How is this regular expression splitting out the strings with the array?

```
String[] words = haystack.split("[ \"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is splitting on any of the following in the character class denoted by the opening `[` and closing `]`:

- – space
- `\"` – quote
- `\'` – apostrophe
- `\t` – tab
- `\n` – line feed
- `\b` – backspace
- `\f` – form feed
- `\r` – carriage return

See the [Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for clarification about regex character classes and characters.

Also, note that `\'` could very well be `'`, escaping being unnecessary in that case.  Check out an [example split on Ideone](http://ideone.com/womO4r) with this little change.

Comment: Can't represent assertions in character classes. Inside, `\b` I believe is a backspace.

Comment: @sln: Right you are. Thanks for catching that. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean haystring (which is a string) is split into an array of strings. All white space characters are used as a delimeter.